# Increasing statistical power by having a highly sensitive outcome measure

Tags: statistical-power, small-sample, type-i-and-ii-errors

Is it logical to say that you can increase statistical power by having a highly sensitive outcome measure? I say this because a highly sensitive test has low Type II error, and low Type II error leads to high power. In one of the articles I was reading, the authors' power analysis revealed that they only needed 6 participants per group, and they believed that it was because their outcome measure was highly sensitive.

Comment: You can achieve perfect (100%) power with a procedure that always rejects the null hypothesis no matter what the data are.  The right way to formulate this question, then, is *given a specified test size,* can the power be increased with a more sensitive measure?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if I'm understanding what you mean by sensitive. You'll get greater power whenever the effect is larger relative to the variation in your measurements. So if your instrument is less variable, that increases power for the same effect size (on the scale of measurement). Or if the instrument responds to a greater degree to a stimulus, without being more variable, that also increases power.

All this is said with the caveat that the sample-size problem is formulated in a way that reflects the needed scientific goals and uses realistic estimates of the error SD(s).